# Apache VirtualHost slow lookup

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I finally managed how to configure properly httpd.conf for my virtualhost needings. This is the relevant part of httpd.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.local
  DocumentRoot /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/test/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName work.local
  DocumentRoot /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/work/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access anything on localhost (i.e. http://localhost/phpmyadmin) everything is very fast.
Whenever I access test.local or work.local (or others I configured) it spends 10-15 seconds on lookup. The following requests are handled correctly and it's very fast but after a minute or so of inactivity, it has to lookup again.

This is my /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
#::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

# Virtualhosts
127.0.0.1       test.local     work.local    yii.local
```

How could I fix this annoying issue?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Add your virtual hosts to the first line:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost test.local work.local yii.local
```

And remove the last line.

That should do the trick. Your vhosts are now an alias for localhost. It's not a good idea to have the same IP-address in multiple lines. This just confuses the DNS-cache.

Comment: Thanks, seems like this fixed my issue!

Comment: I always missed that first localhost (since that part of my file i glossed over). Merging that one really helped.

Comment: Holy **** this so enriched and saved my life! I spent without a doubt one third of the time developing locally waiting for slow loading of local virtual hosts! THANK YOU!

Comment: Just tried the above and added my virtualhosts to the first line and made a huge difference!

Comment: You almost saved half of my lifetime. Love you man. I am going to vote up all your questions.

Answer (score 6):

What fixed it for me was editing **httpd-vhosts.conf** and changing all instances of:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

to:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
```

It was taking about 2-5 seconds to resolve the host, now it is instant. I did not have to modify the order of my sites in my hosts file. This just makes it use ipv4 instead of ipv6 which I'd bet you don't use anyway.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is using Chrome and still gets slow virtual host lookup, you need to change the virtual host name to something else than `.local`, eg. change `test.local` to `test.dev`.

Explanation and source here: http://bencrowder.net/blog/2012/10/slow-localhost-in-chrome/

Comment: THIS was the reason why it took so long for me !!! THANK YOU (BTW: I use Firefox on Win)

Answer (score 0):

You should as well implement other parameters to your vhosts file, like separate error logs and server alias

DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/asd"

    ServerName asd.com.br

    ServerAlias asd.com.br

    ErrorLog "logs/asd.log"

    CustomLog "logs/asd.log" combined

Answer (score 0):

Also setting the ip for ServerName in httpd.conf file worked for me

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
This configuration is for window, but I think it will have been working on Linux too.

### You need to configure 3 files.

```
1-httpd.conf  
2-httpd-vhost.conf  
3-httpd-ssl.conf

General rules
do not use 0.0.0.0:80
do not use 0.0.0.0:443
or 
[::]:80
[::]:443

Keep all original like *:80 *:443
```

---

### 1-httpd.conf

```
(keep original)
Listen *:80 or Listen 80
```

Never define any <VirtualHost *:80 > in httpd.conf, we will define it at httpd-vhost.conf

Never define any <VirtualHost *:443 > in httpd.conf, we will define it at httpd-ssl.conf

Never define any ssl certificate in httpd.conf

otherwise the system is confused make you wait 5s periodically..
Define Directory tag of each vhost like this:

Example:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs2">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

---

### 2- httpd-vhost.conf

Never define any ssl certifiacte in httpd-vhost.conf

Never Never define any <VirtualHost *:443 > in vhost file, we will define it at httpd-ssl.conf

otherwise you have to wait 5sn periodically.

Define  only for 80 port and dont use 0.0.0.0:80 in tags etc, keep original like below

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80  >
    ServerName domain1.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/htdocs"
    ErrorLog  "logs/error-hh2.log"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80  >
    ServerName domain2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/htdocs2"
    ErrorLog  "logs/error-hh2.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### 3- httpd-ssl.conf

Apache is starting to listen 443 port in this file, so after listen 443 or at the bottom add following naturally.

```
(keep original)
Listen 443


#edit existing
<VirtualHost *:443 >
    ServerName domain1.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/htdocs"
    ErrorLog  "logs/error-hh.log"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl_hh/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl_hh/server.key  
    SSLCertificateChainFile conf/ssl_hh/server-ca.key
 #keep FilesMatch or BrowserMatch parameter as original if not needed  
    
</VirtualHost>

#add for second domain
<VirtualHost *:443 >
    ServerName domain2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/htdocs2"
    ErrorLog  "logs/error-hh2.log"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl_hh/server2.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl_hh/server2.key  
    SSLCertificateChainFile conf/ssl_hh/server2-ca.key 
</VirtualHost>
```

That is all.

### Edit :

### !!! Do not forget to add SSLCertificateChainFile CA file.